# SQLAlchemy `session.merge()` is giving `not-null violation` error even though field is not None in the entity object that is passed to session.merge()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm getting error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "model_metadata_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (deployment_record_id, key)=(1c2852bf-89cc-4bf2-8e60-7c6091f12469, key1) already exists.
[SQL: INSERT INTO model_metadata (deployment_record_id, key, value) VALUES (%(deployment_record_id)s, %(key)s, %(value)s)]
[parameters: {'deployment_record_id': '1c2852bf-89cc-4bf2-8e60-7c6091f12469', 'key': 'key1', 'value': 'life'}]
```

Values in the `merged_entity` object,

```
DeploymentRecordEntity(id='1c2852bf-89cc-4bf2-8e60-7c6091f12469', create_time=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), modify_time=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), name='sdw', description='Deployment 6 description', owner_id=UUID('95e840ed-747f-4df5-ba55-8c7cb8fd104e'), tags=['tag6', 'tag7'], model_id='e2fbd953-90b8-4874-8b5b-050a2c3c61e5', model_name='Model 6', model_description='Model 6 description', model_source='Model 6 source', model_metadata=[ModelMetadataEntity(deployment_record_id='1c2852bf-89cc-4bf2-8e60-7c6091f12469', key='key1', value='life'), ModelMetadataEntity(deployment_record_id=UUID('1c2852bf-89cc-4bf2-8e60-7c6091f12469'), key='key4', value='serial')], column_definition=[ColumnDefinitionEntity(id=UUID('b25d2d7f-c8a5-4a1f-beef-6b735386c25b'), deployment_record_id=UUID('1c2852bf-89cc-4bf2-8e60-7c6091f12469'), name='thal', logical_type='2', storage_type='1', variable_importance=3.0, user_importance=3.0, baseline_data=['456', '434', '434'])])
```

**Here is the code that I'm using to merge two `DeploymentRecordEntity` objects,**

```
    def update_deployment_record(
        self, session: Session, deployment: DeploymentRecordEntity
    ) -> None:
        fetched_entity: Optional[DeploymentRecordEntity] = session.query(DeploymentRecordEntity)
            .filter(DeploymentRecordEntity.id == deployment.id)
            .first()

        if fetched_entity:
            merged_entity: DeploymentRecordEntity = update_entity_with_non_empty_fields(fetched_entity, deployment)
            session.merge(merged_entity)
            session.commit()
```

Here're my util functions that I used to merge two objects,

```
def update_entity_with_non_empty_fields(entity1: Base, entity2: Base) -> Any:
    for attr in entity2.__dict__:
        if attr != "_sa_instance_state":
            value = getattr(entity2, attr)
            if not _is_empty(value):
                setattr(entity1, attr, value)
    return entity1


def _is_empty(value: Any) -> bool:
    return (
        value is None
        or (isinstance(value, list) and not value)
        or (isinstance(value, dict) and not value)
        or (isinstance(value, str) and not value.strip())
        or (isinstance(value, datetime) and value == datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
    )
```

Here're the entity classes,

```
class DeploymentRecordEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "deployment_record"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        String, default=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False
    )
    create_time: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now(), nullable=False
    )
    modify_time: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now(), nullable=False
    )
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    description: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    owner_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None, nullable=False)
    tags: Mapped[List[str]] = mapped_column(ARRAY(String), default=None)
    model_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    model_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    model_description: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    model_source: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None)

    model_metadata: Mapped[Optional[List[ModelMetadataEntity]]] = relationship(
        default=None,
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    )

    column_definition: Mapped[Optional[List[ColumnDefinitionEntity]]] = relationship(
        default=None,
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    )
```

```
class ModelMetadataEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "model_metadata"

    deployment_record_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("deployment_record.id"),
        default=None,
        nullable=False,
    )
    key: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        String, default=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False
    )
    value: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None, nullable=False)
```

```
class ColumnDefinitionEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "column_definition"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        String, default=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False
    )
    deployment_record_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("deployment_record.id"),
        default=None,
        nullable=False,
    )
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    logical_type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    storage_type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    variable_importance: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, default=None)
    user_importance: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    baseline_data: Mapped[List[str]] = mapped_column(ARRAY(String), default=None)
```

Comment: This code doesn't run - looks like the relationship is misconfigured.

Comment: @snakecharmerb sorry, I updated the code. I think the issue is with the removal of `_sa_instance_state` state field from the SA entity classes during the merge by `update_entity_with_non_empty_fields` function. I think, that function doesn't work in the right way. I need to find a way to  merge two objects from `DeploymentRecordEntity` class before passing it into `session.merge()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the `update_entity_with_non_empty_fields(entity1: Base, entity2: Base) -> Any` function that I used to merge two `DeploymentEntityRecord` objects. In SA, it's mandatory have `_sa_instance_state` field in the object and that field is used to keep the track of the state of the object when merging by using `session.merge()`.

So I managed to implement set of util functions that does the job in the right way,

```
def merge_deployment_record_entity(
    obj1: DeploymentRecordEntity, obj2: DeploymentRecordEntity
) -> DeploymentRecordEntity:
    merged_obj = DeploymentRecordEntity(
        id=obj2.id if obj2.id is not None and obj2.id != "" else obj1.id,
        create_time=obj1.create_time,  # Keep the original create_time
        modify_time=datetime.now()
        if obj2.modify_time is (None or datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
        else obj2.modify_time,  # Update the modify_time to the current time
        name=obj2.name if obj2.name is not None and obj2.name != "" else obj1.name,
        description=obj2.description
        if obj2.description is not None
        else obj1.description,
        owner_id=obj2.owner_id
        if obj2.owner_id is not None and obj2.owner_id != ""
        else obj1.owner_id,
        tags=obj2.tags if obj2.tags is not None else obj1.tags,
        model_id=obj2.model_id
        if obj2.model_id is not None and obj2.model_id != ""
        else obj1.model_id,
        model_name=obj2.model_name
        if obj2.model_name is not None and obj2.model_name != ""
        else obj1.model_name,
        model_description=obj2.model_description
        if obj2.model_description is not None
        else obj1.model_description,
        model_source=obj2.model_source
        if obj2.model_source is not None and obj2.model_source != ""
        else obj1.model_source,
        model_metadata=merge_model_metadata(obj1.model_metadata, obj2.model_metadata),
        column_definition=merge_column_definition(
            obj1.column_definition, obj2.column_definition
        ),
    )
    return merged_obj


def merge_model_metadata(
    metadata1: Optional[List[ModelMetadataEntity]],
    metadata2: Optional[List[ModelMetadataEntity]],
) -> Optional[List[ModelMetadataEntity]]:
    if metadata2 is None:
        return metadata1
    if metadata1 is None:
        return metadata2

    merged_metadata = metadata1.copy()

    for item2 in metadata2:
        existing_item_index = next(
            (
                index
                for index, item1 in enumerate(merged_metadata)
                if item1.deployment_record_id == item2.deployment_record_id
                and item1.key == item2.key
            ),
            None,
        )
        if existing_item_index is not None:
            merged_metadata[existing_item_index] = item2
        else:
            merged_metadata.append(item2)

    return merged_metadata


def merge_column_definition(
    definition1: Optional[List[ColumnDefinitionEntity]],
    definition2: Optional[List[ColumnDefinitionEntity]],
) -> Optional[List[ColumnDefinitionEntity]]:
    if definition2 is None:
        return definition1
    if definition1 is None:
        return definition2

    merged_definition = definition1.copy()

    for item2 in definition2:
        existing_item_index = next(
            (
                index
                for index, item1 in enumerate(merged_definition)
                if item1.id == item2.id
            ),
            None,
        )
        if existing_item_index is not None:
            merged_definition[existing_item_index] = item2
        else:
            merged_definition.append(item2)

    return merged_definition
```